# How to reduce white space above/around R-Plot in LaTeX-Beamer document

Tags: beamer, subfloats, r

**Hi guys,**

my header looks like:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\input{ix-utf8enc.dfu}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{crane}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
\usepackage{float}
```

I use R-Sweave to process R-code within the LaTeX Document. Everything works fine except positioning of the R-plots. There always seems to be a huge margin - especially above the plots. How can I reduce it?

A little bit of example code:

```
\begin{frame}[label=5]
\begin{figure}[h]
<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
plot(100:240, 100:240, type = "n", xlab="X-Koordinate", ylab="Y-Koordinate", frame.plot="FALSE" )
@
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

I also tried to work with subfloats:

```
\begin{frame}[label=4]
\begin{figure}[ht]
\subfloat{
<<label=test, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE>>=
plot(100:240, 100:240, type = "n", xlab="X-Koordinate", ylab="Y-Koordinate", frame.plot="TRUE")
@
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{sweave-test}}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

I hope you have an idea!
Thanks

Comment: this might be more of an R than LaTeX question ... R allows you to set margins via the `par` option - the defaults are quite large - e.g. `par(mar=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1) )`

Comment: Great - that's it! I tried for an eternity to fix my LaTeX-setting - and finally it's an R-problem.

Comment: Hm - it works for some plots, but not for the density-plots which I create with the package "spatstat". That's strange...

Comment: I am not familiar with `spatstat`  -but some R packages have their own settings with redefine `par()` commands you've set & you might be encountering a case of that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about margins added to a graphic by R, and modifying the R-code solved the problem.